# How to monitor multiple assets at the same time with a trading robot?

Tags: python, python-3.8, trading

I am developing a trading robot in Python 3.8 and I need to know if you can give me any ideas to monitor multiple open orders simultaneously.

The situation is as follows: When you want to sell an asset, the robot can monitor conditions permanently and easily evaluate the indicators to place the sell order (limit or market).

But when you have 3, 4, 5 assets or more the situation gets complicated because the robot monitors one asset and then moves on to the next one and so on. This means that when monitoring asset # 2 (for example) asset # 5 (which is not being monitored) may be suffering a sudden strong fluctuation that makes you lose money.

My question is: Is there a way to keep an eye on all 5 assets at the same time?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to create a surveillance module for each asset to be traded. I don't know if this makes a lot of sense and I don't know how I could do it either.

Comment: Computers are really fast.  You ought to be able to check thousands of assets many times per second.  If that isn't fast enough, then what you want is to work from a stream of delta values...that is, changes to the underlying assets. For stocks, these are "ticks". Then you do nothing until something changes, and then you immediately look right to the asset that has changed.  If you don't have delta data, all you can do is poll...asking for the current value of each asset in turn, and behaving appropriately. Still, polling should be fine unless your trading relies on sub-second decision making.

Comment: ...in fact, the limiting factor is usually how fast you can get your data off the internet, not the speed of your code.  This is why lightning traders pay to have their offices right next to the big exchanges, and then run dedicated fibre optics right to the exchanges.  They say that a microsecond can be the difference between a winning and losing trade for those guys.  I recommend that you not try to compete with those traders by relying on reliable sub-second changes. - for whatever you do, concentrate on keeping your local price model as up to date as possible.   That's the tricky part.

Comment: Yes, computers are very fast, but the same is not the case with Internet connection. Keep in mind that the universe of assets to monitor is not insignificant and the execution of indicators can take a second or two depending on whether the computer needs to make several requests to the server. Imagine that you must evaluate purchase conditions in a universe of 700 cryptocurrencies and at the same time attend to the sale of about 30 or 50 assets. Time is money here and the speed of a pc falls short. That is why I can think of some kind of division into modules, like clusters.

Comment: I agree with you @Steve. I am not trying to compete against sharks. Local pricing model ... that sounds interesting, but it still doesn't solve the simultaneous monitoring problem. But imagine that you have your PC divided into 10 parts (clusters) and each one is in charge of monitoring an asset. Do you think that is possible by creating different modules in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigating thoroughly on this problem I found a way to theoretically and technically solve this problem. This is multiprocessing in Python.

The technique consists of distributing the memory of our PC in portions to execute the same process many times and at the same time.

Graphically I explain it with the following images. Python runs sequentially as we see in this image:

[image]

This has the consequence that if the monitoring loop is calculating the indicators of asset 1, then asset 130 (for example) is unsupervised and could generate considerable losses.

But if we divide the memory of our machine or use multiple cores, we can execute the same process at the same time for several assets, as I show in the following image:

[image]

In this link you can see the result of applying a multithreading (take a good look at the time) and a multiprocess: http://pythondiario.com/2018/07/multihilo-y-multiprocesamiento.html

I also leave the link of the library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

More information and more detailed examples of multiprocessing can be seen here: https://www.genbeta.com/desarrollo/multiprocesamiento-en-python-benchmarking

It only remains to develop the code and put it to the test.